# XCTest doesn't measure CPU and memory

Tags: ios, iphone, performance-testing, xctest

I have this performance test to check Memory usage during scrolling.

```
func testMemotyUsage() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let measureOptions = XCTMeasureOptions()
    measureOptions.invocationOptions = [.manuallyStop]

    measure(
      metrics: [XCTMemoryMetric(application: app)],
      options: measureOptions
    ) {
      app.buttons["Listing Page"].tap()

      swipeUp()

      stopMeasuring()

      tapBack()
    }
  }

func tapBack() {
    app.navigationBars.buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
  }

func swipeUp() {
    collectionView.swipeUp(velocity: .fast)
  }

func swipeDown() {
    collectionView.swipeDown(velocity: .fast)
  }

var collectionView: XCUIElement {
    app.collectionViews["collectionViewId"]
  }
```

But when I run the test, it doesn't display any metrics at all.

[image]

I tried to update
`XCTMemoryMetric(application: app)` -> to `XCTMemoryMetric()`

In this case it at least shows some result, but the result is incorrect, because as it's seen on the screenshot below, the app consumes around 130 MB of memory, **but the test shows 9 KB only**. BTW the real memory consumption is around 130-150 MB, because there are a lot of images in the collection view.

[image]
[image]

My guess that it doesn't show the correct result, because the `app` is not passed as a parameter. Although when I pass the `app`, it doesn't show any results at all

Same issue happens when I write the test to check CPU usage with `XCTCPUMetric`.

**Questions:**

1. How to write a performance test that will show memory and CPU usage of some UI tests?
2. (Optional) Why when I run the test in Debug mode, it shows that 2 processes are running (`ExampleUITests` - the target for UI tests, and `Example` - the main target). Is it normal and when I measure the memory consumption, am I supposed to get the consumption of the main target `Example`, right?